# Oracle Sql non duplicate column data

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to produce data in this format r_regionkey r_name: list of n_name

Example:

```
0 Africa: Algeria, Ethiopia, kenya ...
1 America: argentina,brazil ...
```

However my current code produces this output:

```
0Africa: algeria   ,  0Afria : Ethiopia
1America: argentina   1America: brazil
```

Appreciate if someone could help me, thanks.

Below is my code

```
create or replace function LISTNATION (region_name varchar2)
return varchar2 is
    myOutput varchar2(10000);
begin
    myOutput := '';
    for curNation in (select r_regionkey, r_name,n_name
                      from region, nation
                      where r_regionkey = n_regionkey)
    loop
        myOutput := myOutput||curNation.r_regionkey||curNation.r_name|| ':'||curNation.n_name || ',' ;
    end loop;
    return trim(myOutput);
end LISTNATION;
/

select listnation('EUROPE') from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need LISTAGG probably. Update your code to -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LISTNATION (region_name VARCHAR2)
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  myOutput VARCHAR2(10000);
BEGIN
  myOutput := '';
  FOR curNation IN (SELECT r_regionkey, r_name, LISTAGG(n_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY n_name) n_name
                      FROM region, nation
                     WHERE r_regionkey = n_regionkey
                     GROUP BY r_regionkey, r_name) LOOP
     myOutput := myOutput || curNation.r_regionkey || curNation.r_name || ':' || curNation.n_name;
     END LOOP;
   RETURN TRIM(myOutput);
END LISTNATION;
/
```